# PascalCase with jsx extension or camelCase without it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When I import jsx component from file with PascalCase name, I should use file extension:

```
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar.jsx'
```

String without extension will give me error:

```
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar'
```

I can write without extension like this:

```
import { Navbar } from './components/navbar'
```

But as far as I know, React guidelines demand to use PascalCase filenames.
So what option is more correct?

Comment: You answered it yourself, only the first option works and 3rd option is not with the guidelines

Comment: The last option might work if you use `case-insensitive` OS like `windows` not in case sensitive OS file system. It's better practice to follow the preferred conventions/guidelines to avoid unnecessary bugs.